# How to call a function from console if it's inside another function?

Tags: javascript

I am by no means a web developer.
I'm trying to call function foo() from developer console which is placed inside another function boo() as shown below:

```
function boo(options) {
    function foo() {
        --somecode--
    }


    var onDrop = function() {
        foo();
    };
}
```

It does not work and throw "not defined" error because it's not in the scope. Yet, foo can be called with events such as onDrop.
Basically, what I want is calling foo directly from console. Is it possible?

Comment: no, there's no way to access an inner function from outside

Comment: No. Not unless you pause at a debug breakpoint inside the function where it's in scope.

Comment: Consider trying to fire the `onDrop` event handler instead (assuming it is attached to an accessible object)

Comment: So am I forced to call it through events? @gog

Comment: @Bergi ok nvm...